# HTML or CSS layout issue...? (Html smaller than viewport)

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this website: www.artetia.com

The thing is that when I resize my viewport I get a white stripe in the right side of the browser as if the Body of my website is smaller or having a minimum width. Can't find how to solve this, I tried with Firebug to check the structure and seems that the html can't get smaller than 960px or so...

Comment: You are going to have to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or something for people to see what is happening.

Comment: OSX Chrome, the only white bar im seeing on that website is the scrollbar. Can you provide an image of the problem, and the browsers/OS's you've tested this on

Comment: No white bar here either!

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the backgrounds being wiped out when the viewport is narrowed below 960px. Here's one way to do that via CSS:

```
div[id^="slide"] {min-width: 960px;}
```

(For those not seeing the issue, it's a common layout issue. If you narrow the browser below 960px, a horizontal scroll bar appears; and if you scroll right, the backgrounds have been wiped.)

Comment: I haven't seen that before! Could you explain what's going on and what causes it?

Comment: I don't understand it in a highly technical way. But it's a very common phenomenon. In fixed width layouts, if elements have a background color but no minimum width, they will shrink as the browser narrows. When you then scroll to the right, their background in the hidden area has been wiped out and doesn't repaint when you scroll that hidden area into view. (No doubt there's a more technical way to describe it. It's becoming less of an issue as sites become more responsive.)